# How to check is there a record in ArrayList Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that creates a new student with his own ID. And after that I want to check by id does a student exists. What I am doing wrong right now? Because all the time only else statement works.

```
ArrayList<Studentas> studentuSarasas = new ArrayList<Studentas>();
protected int studentoID;
protected String studentoVardas;
protected String studentoPavarde;
protected String pirmasDalykas;
protected String antrasDalykas;
protected String treciasDalykas;
protected String ketvirtasDalykas;
protected String penktasDalykas;
protected int pirmoPaz;
protected int antroPaz;
protected int trecioPaz;
protected int ketvirtoPaz;
protected int penktoPaz;

Studentas() {
}

public Studentas(int studentoID, String studentoVardas, String studentoPavarde, String pirmasDalykas, String antrasDalykas, String treciasDalykas, String ketvirtasDalykas, String penktasDalykas, int pirmoPaz, int antroPaz, int trecioPaz, int ketvirtoPaz, int penktoPaz) {
    this.studentoID = studentoID;
    this.studentoVardas = studentoVardas;
    this.studentoPavarde = studentoPavarde;
    this.pirmasDalykas = pirmasDalykas;
    this.antrasDalykas = antrasDalykas;
    this.treciasDalykas = treciasDalykas;
    this.ketvirtasDalykas = ketvirtasDalykas;
    this.penktasDalykas = penktasDalykas;
    this.pirmoPaz = pirmoPaz;
    this.antroPaz = antroPaz;
    this.trecioPaz = trecioPaz;
    this.ketvirtoPaz = ketvirtoPaz;
    this.penktoPaz = penktoPaz;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Studento numeris: " + studentoID +
            ", Vardas: " + studentoVardas +
            ", Pavarde: " + studentoPavarde +
            ", Pasirenkamas dalykas: " + pirmasDalykas +
            ", Pasirenkamas dalykas: " + antrasDalykas +
            ", Pasirenkamas dalykas: " + treciasDalykas +
            ", Pasirenkamas dalykas: " + ketvirtasDalykas +
            ", Pasirenkamas dalykas: " + penktasDalykas +
            ", Pirmojo dalyko pazymys: " + pirmoPaz +
            ", Antrojo dalyko pazymys: " + antroPaz +
            ", Treciojo dalyko pazymys: " + trecioPaz +
            ", Ketvirtojo dalyko pazymys: " + ketvirtoPaz +
            ", Penktojo dalyko pazymys: " + penktoPaz;
}
```

Here's how I create my student:

```
private void studentoSukurimas() {
    System.out.println("ID, name, surn, studthing1- studthing5 ,averages from 1 to 5");
    Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] iveda = SI.nextLine().split(" ");
    studentuSarasas.add(new Studentas(Integer.parseInt(iveda[0]), iveda[1], iveda[2], iveda[3], iveda[4], iveda[5], iveda[6], iveda[7], Integer.parseInt(iveda[8]), Integer.parseInt(iveda[9]), Integer.parseInt(iveda[10]), Integer.parseInt(iveda[11]), Integer.parseInt(iveda[12])));
    System.out.println("gut");
    Pasirinkimai();
}
```

And this is my code where I check does the student by ID exists:

```
 private void studentasPagalId() {
    System.out.println("student id");
    Scanner SI = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userSelects = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
    String q = Integer.toString(userSelects);
    if(q.equals(getStudentoID())) {
        System.out.println("+");
    } else {
        System.out.println("-");
    }
    Pasirinkimai();
}
```

Comment: You're not using any list in the method supposed to check if a student exists in a list. So it can't be correct. And you only posted two unrelated, incomplete  parts of the code, so it's pretty hard to help. If you want help, post a minimal complete example reproducing the issue, and use meaningful method and variables names.

Comment: Variables names are meaningful for me, if you're talking about the line with String q... in second code so sorry, because this one was my last check. I will update my code

Comment: But you're not asking the question to yourself. You're asking it to us. So the question and its code should be clear for us, not for you.

Comment: I believe it's ok to change variables names to english language if code is short, but in other way ...

Comment: @HenrikasB If `getStudentoID()` is returning an `int`/`Integer` value, then your code check `q.equals(getStudentoID())` will not work because you are comparing a `String` with an `int`/`Integer`, which will always be `false`.

Comment: show the code of this `getStudentoID()` and also why this conversion string to int and again int to string `int userSelects = Integer.parseInt(SI.nextLine());
    String q = Integer.toString(userSelects);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try to check every element of a list, you can use a for.

```
for(int i=0; i<studentuSarasas.size();i++){
    if(q.equals(studentuSarasas.get(i).getStudentoID()))
        ...
}
```